# Jquery runtime div's not printing properly

Tags: jquery

The code below is supposed to grab the news feed from a json object and print the news one below each other in a stacked format like this

2013
 - 1
   - News 1
   - News 2
 - 2 
   - News 1
   - News 2
2012
 - 1
   - News 1
   - News 2
 - 2 
   - News 1
   - News 2

Here is my feed

```
    {
  "currentYear": "2013",
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "33",
      "year": "2012",
      "month": "3",
      "day": "25",
      "sourcename": "WSF",
      "title": "Test",
      "url": "www.test.com",
      "ingress": "data"
    },
    {
      "id": "72",
      "year": "2012",
      "month": "1",
      "day": "20",
      "sourcename": "SF times",
      "title": "Test 1 ",
      "url": "www.gogole.com",
      "ingress": "data"
    }
  ]
}
```

here is my jquery

```
var date = new Date();
var currentYear = date.getFullYear();
var id;
var div_year_id;
var div_month_id;
var tmp_div_year_id;
var i = 1;


$.each(feed.data, function(key, val){

    if(tmp_div_year_id != "#" + val.year) {
        div_year_id     = "#" + val.year;
        div_month_id    = "#" + val.year + "_" + val.month;
    }

    //check if the div for the year exists
    if($(div_year_id).length > 0) {
        console.log("adding year");
        // check if the div for the month exists
        if($(div_month_id).length > 0) {
            console.log("adding month")
            // append to the div year id
        } else {
            //create the month id
            $(div_year_id).append('<div id='+ div_month_id + '></div>');
        }
    } else {
        //create the year id
        $("#news").append('<div id='+ div_year_id + '><div id='+ div_month_id +'><h1>' + val.title + '</h1><p><em>Date</em>: '+ val.year + '-' + val.month + '-' + val.day +'</p><p>' + val.ingress +'</p><p><em>Source</em>: '+ val.sourcename + '</em></p><p><a href="'+ val.url +'" target="_blank">Read full article >></a></p></div>');
        $(div_year_id).append('<div id='+ div_month_id + '></div>');

        tmp_div_year_id = div_year_id;
    }
    console.log(tmp_div_year_id);
    i++;
});
```

the code is not stacking the news properly in one div for each year it creates a new div for each year

Comment: can you prepare a demo in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you are creating your div's; you are creating them including `#` char in the id.

I change your code in (look at the main else statement with **create the year id** comment) and create them without the # in the id:

```
if ($(div_year_id).length > 0) {
    console.log("adding year");
    // check if the div for the month exists
    if ($(div_month_id).length > 0) {
        console.log("adding month")
        // append to the div year id
    } else {
        //create the month id
        $(div_year_id).append('<div id=' + val.month + '></div>');
    }
} else {
    //create the year id
    $("#news").append('<div id=' + val.year + '><div id=' + val.month + '><h1>' + val.title + '</h1><p><em>Date</em>: ' + val.year + '-' + val.month + '-' + val.day + '</p><p>' + val.ingress + '</p><p><em>Source</em>: ' + val.sourcename + '</em></p><p><a href="' + val.url + '" target="_blank">Read full article >></a></p></div>');
    $(div_year_id).append('<div id=' + val.month + '></div>');

    tmp_div_year_id = div_year_id;
}
```

and now your if statements are working as expected, working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/K6aHe/3